# Integración Continua con docker y gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

Soy nuevo en el tema y me gustaría tener una explicación tipo **dummies**.

Me piden tener un entorno de este tipo para realizar la integración:

- SO:Debian9
- CURL
- NIX
- DOCKER
- GITLAB

Cuales serian los pasos a seguir y debo tener en cuenta?

Comment: Que has probado hasta el momento? La instalación de las app que indicas son  en cierto modo sencillas... Comento para seguir este hilo, me parece interesante

Comment: Tengo todo instalado, solo que en el momento de hacer el commit el Pipelines falla. no se que estoy omitiendo. he visto infinidades de vídeos aun tengo dudas como se hace la integración.

Answer (score 1):

Integracion continua es el proceso de construir y correr varios pasos a tu codigo (como construir, correrle una suite de tests, y contruir una nueva imagen de docker), todo cuando detecta un cambio.

Para ello primero debes tener una herramienta que corra esos pasos, y pueda detectar los cambios en un repositorio de codigo como github por ejemplo.

**GITLAB:** Combina varias cosas juntas, es un controlador de versiones de codigo (como github), pero ademas trae la capacidad de usarlo como herramienta de Integracion Continua como Jenkins, y ademas trae un repositorio de Imagenes de Docker como Dockerhub)

**SO:Debian9:** 
Es el Sistema Operativo, si usas docker puedes bajar una imagen con:
`docker pull debian`

**Curl:** Es una libreria de docker que permite transferir datos y hacer peticiones HTTP, a veces viene por defecto en ciertas distribuciones de linux.

**Docker** Docker es una alternativa a las Maquinas virtuales

Comment: Amigo lo que busco es como son los pasos para realizar la integracion de mi codigo y como hacer los test.